# Python : using awk with multiple variables in subprocess.call

Tags: python, awk, terminal, subprocess, pdb

I'm working with a PDB file which contains multiple records. Here is an example file if you're not familiar with this type of format:

HEADER    GROWTH FACTOR                           16-JAN-96   1KLA

SOURCE    MOL_ID: 1;

REMARK 210 EXPERIMENTAL DETAILS

REMARK 210  EXPERIMENT TYPE               :NMR

SSBOND   7 CYS B   15    CYS B   78                          1555   1555  2.02

SSBOND   8 CYS B   44    CYS B  109                          1555   1555  2.01

MODEL        1

ATOM      1  N   ALA A   1       9.028  -1.949 -15.575  1.00  0.00           N

ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   1       7.983  -2.064 -14.518  1.00  0.00           C

TER

ATOM   1770  N   ALA B   1      -9.094  -0.752  15.747  1.00  0.00           N

ATOM   1771  CA  ALA B   1      -8.052  -0.952  14.700  1.00  0.00           C

ENDMDL

CONECT   98  225

CONECT  215 1211

END

I want to keep only certain records from this file : (SSBOND, ATOM, MODEL,TER,CONECT,ENDMDL) and remove the others. For this I've made a python script which takes a pdb_file.pdb in input and creates an output file pdb_clean.pdb :

```
import subprocess

def prep_molecule(pdb_file):

    pdb_fileName = pdb_file.split(".")[0]
    subprocess.call(['awk \'"\$1==\\"SSBOND\\" || \$1==\\"ATOM\\" || \$1==\\"TER\\" || \$1==\\"CONECT\\" || \$1==\\"END\\" || \$1==\\"MODEL\\" || \$1==\\"ENDMDL\\"\\' +pdb_file+' > '+pdb_fileName+'_clean.pdb"'],shell=True)
```

Maybe the problem comes from the quotes. I keep having the same error :

```
awk: command line:1: ^syntax error
```

Actually I'm making a Python script because awk is not the only command I'm running. My goal is to automate a full pipeline of protein dynamics, so Python is necessary ...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I fail to see the point in using `awk` inside python when python can do much better and simpler...

Comment: Real answer, don't use awk, use Python. Anything you can do with awk, Python can do, so you are over complicating it. However, you are building a command string and passing it to call in one step. Instead, create the command string and assign it to variable. Print the variable, then pass the variable to call. You should see in the print statement the syntax error in your awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to just use `awk` as python seems somewhat uneccessary for this fairly straightforward task, however, here is a solution using awk within python:

File:

```
$ cat pbd_file.pbd
HEADER GROWTH FACTOR 16-JAN-96 1KLA

SOURCE MOL_ID: 1;

REMARK 210 EXPERIMENTAL DETAILS

REMARK 210 EXPERIMENT TYPE :NMR

SSBOND 7 CYS B 15 CYS B 78 1555 1555 2.02

SSBOND 8 CYS B 44 CYS B 109 1555 1555 2.01

MODEL 1

ATOM 1 N ALA A 1 9.028 -1.949 -15.575 1.00 0.00 N

ATOM 2 CA ALA A 1 7.983 -2.064 -14.518 1.00 0.00 C

TER

ATOM 1770 N ALA B 1 -9.094 -0.752 15.747 1.00 0.00 N

ATOM 1771 CA ALA B 1 -8.052 -0.952 14.700 1.00 0.00 C

ENDMDL

CONECT 98 225

CONECT 215 1211

END
```

Python script is as follows (use of `sys.argv[1]` means you can pass whatever file you want as an argument from the command line):

```
import subprocess, sys

def prep_molecule(pdb_file):
    pdb_fileName = pdb_file.split(".")[0]
    subprocess.call(['awk \'$1~"SSBOND|ATOM|TER|CONECT|END|MODEL|ENDMDL"\' "'+pdb_file+'" > "'+pdb_fileName+'_clean.pdb"'],shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prep_molecule(sys.argv[1])
```

Then, "clean" the file with python script:

```
$ python pdb_clean.py pdb_file.pdb
```

Results:

```
$ cat pdb_file_clean.pdb
SSBOND 7 CYS B 15 CYS B 78 1555 1555 2.02
SSBOND 8 CYS B 44 CYS B 109 1555 1555 2.01
MODEL 1
ATOM 1 N ALA A 1 9.028 -1.949 -15.575 1.00 0.00 N
ATOM 2 CA ALA A 1 7.983 -2.064 -14.518 1.00 0.00 C
TER
ATOM 1770 N ALA B 1 -9.094 -0.752 15.747 1.00 0.00 N
ATOM 1771 CA ALA B 1 -8.052 -0.952 14.700 1.00 0.00 C
ENDMDL
CONECT 98 225
CONECT 215 1211
END
```

Comment: Actually I'm making a Python script because the awk command is not the only one I'm running. My goal is to automate a full pipeline of protein dynamics, so Python is necessary ...

Comment: @Luc amended answer in response to your requirements, but you might be better to create a shell script if possible, or if not, read the file in python and manage it that way